# Finding the Fourier series for a function on a defined interval

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Consider the function
$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
0 \ \ &-4\leq x < -2,\\
4 - x^2 \ \ &-2\leq x \leq 2, \\
0  \  \  &2 < x \leq 4
\end{cases}$$

Defined on the interval $[-4,4]$. Find the Fourier series of $\phi$.

Is this the equation I need to use?
$$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\cos\frac{n\pi x}{l} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin\frac{n\pi x}{l}$$

Comment: You forgot the summation sign before $B_n$.

Comment: And you need to think about what $\ell$ would be in that equation...

Comment: The definition of the ranges for $\phi (x)$ is incorrect.  I think you meant $2\le x\le 4$ for the third interval.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Ah, yes I did, thank you.

Comment: @MarkFischler would $l$ be 4?